# Can we update the time interval on .writeValue(ble, for: char, type: .withResponse)

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

When I write data to BLE as follows,

```
.writeValue(ble, for: char, type: .withResponse)
```

sometime I get bluetooth timeout error and app gets disconnected with the peripheral.

We found that the root cause is that there is some set of delay(few seconds) for the peripheral to response for some data.

So can we set/configure timeout value for this case?

**Note*** This issue occurs on iOS alone, looks like I need to tweak the timeout case.

Comment: Your question is about iOS coding. Please don't use the ESP32 tag on questions that have nothing to do with ESP32.

Comment: Do you mean that your peripheral is built so that if you send a request "too early", the peripheral will misbehave and disconnect eventually due to timeout?

Comment: Ya kind of @Emil. What exactly happens here is, when we send a data when board is ready to receive the board gets disconnected while receiving the first data(512 bytes) bcz board is writing data into memory and it takes few milliseconds of delay and in mean time the disconnection occurs. But without the writing to memory the transfer is completely fine.